# How do I get just the directory part of a path in Perl?

Tags: perl

I have the array like below. I want to remove the last work from it using Perl.

```
my @array = 'directory1/directory2/directory3/log_info.txt';
```

I want to get the directory structure without `log_info.txt`.

e.g want output `directory1/directory2/directory3/`

Comment: What you shows is wrong. `@array` is an array the other side is a string.

Comment: @Jens wouldn't that just create an array of one item? I agree OP probably wants to use `$array` though.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Below line working for me.

```
$array =~ s/log_info.txt//g;
```

Comment: What happens if that string is in the middle of the path, or if the filename has that substring (say, `new_log_info.txt.gz`)? Your example only works in this particular case by accident.

Answer (score 3):

[File::Basename](http://perldoc.perl.org/File/Basename.html) is a conventional and portable way to parse a file path with Perl.

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use File::Basename qw(dirname);

my @array = 'directory1/directory2/directory3/log_info.txt';
for (@array) {
    print dirname($_), "/\n";
}
```

Output:

```
directory1/directory2/directory3/
```

Answer (score -2):

There is probably a better way to do this but here is a quick and dirty fix:

```
$/ = "log_info.txt";
chomp(@array);
```

Will cut off the last part.

Alternatively you could use regex:

```
my ($dir) = @array[0] =~ /(.*)\/log_info.txt/;
```

Comment: why your regex is giving output as 1 ?

Comment: I was missing the parens around `$dir`. Fixed.

Comment: Why round brackets made the difference ? Can you please explain the reason ? why you have to use round brackets for the variable in this case ?

Comment: Notice the part of the regex with the parentheses? `(.*)` What perl is doing here is saying "This is what I want to return." And it then stores that part of the string in the special variable `$1`. I could have done `my $dir = $1` afterwards and gotten the result that way. Instead I match the parentheses and tell perl to put what it found in `(.*)` inside the variable `($dir)`.

Comment: If you are going to mess around with Perl's special variables, change them with `local` in their own scope so they don't affect the rest of the program. Once you've done that it's not so quick anymore. Then, make that general for any path and not just the one stated.